# WSO2ESB concat input file name with SYSTEM_DATE

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am going to concat input file name with SYSTEM_DATE below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="importclassroomcourse"
   transports="https,http,local"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                  expression="fn:concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '-', get-property('filename'), '.xml')"/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="https://qa-abc.com/api/classroom/xyz"/>
  </endpoint>
  </target>
   <description/>
  </proxy>
```

But it won't concat the file name below is the log

```
 LogMediator transport.vfs.ReplyFileName = 160316122250-.xml
```

Kindly guide me how can i get the file name because file name is missing.I have sent the file test.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any initialisation of property 'filename' in your mediation : this property does not exist and therefore, has no value when used in 'concat'.

What do you mean by "I have sent the file text.xlsx" ? Your proxy use http and local transport, it's not a VFS proxy scanning a directory to load files ?

You can define this property :

```
<property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"                  expression="fn:concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '-test.xml')"/>
```

but after that, you must use send with a vfs endpoint inside the inSequence to write the file (in your case, there is a https endpoint)

If your proxy were a VFS proxy, you could use FILE_NAME on scope transport to get incoming filename.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Michel. "I have sent the file text.xlsx" ? It's means i sent file from postman. 
Actually i just want to check the incoming file extension only. 
I sent file from Postman with .xlsx extension via http Postman request if incoming file at ESB not xlsx then i need to send error message in response.
Kindly guide me

Comment: I don't know postman, but you need to access the file extension inside the mediation : how does postman send this information in the post request ? I guess it's a http header ? Use tcpmon (have a look to ESB_HOME/bin/) to verify the post details.  Inside the inSequence, you can use get-property('transport', 'MyHttpHeader') to get such headers.

Comment: I have changed the code as below:
       <log level="custom">
            <property name="filereceivefrompostman"
                      expression="get-property('transport', 'filename')"/>
         </log>
But still not getting name console log is
INFO - LogMediator filereceivefrompostman = null 
But ESB Log showing below detail
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.xlsx"

Comment: how can i extract filename from     Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.xlsx

Comment: use get-property('transport','Content-Disposition') with appropriate xpath functions : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp#string

Comment: when i simply try to log get-property('transport','Content-Disposition') it will print null